# Monotonic function vs bounded variation vs being bounded and Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently learning analysis from Rudin's Analysis book. In the chapter about integration he is talking about bounded variation of a function. So if the function f(x) defined on (a,b) is monotonic then it has bounded variation on (a,b) and thus it is bounded. This will also imply that the function is Riemann integrable.

I am not quite understanding why a monotonic function defined on (a,b) can always be bounded. Actually it must not ( say that at the point b it might diverge ). Since being bounded is a necessary condition for a function to be Riemann inegrable, there is also a problem of integrability if one assumes only the monotony of f.

I know Rudin must be right but i don't see the point where i am wrong.

Can somebody explain where is the point which is misleading me ?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: That ought to be a closed interval, if $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$, then it has bounded variation and is bounded. For open intervals, that need not hold.

Comment: Thanks. In the case of a closed interval, without any other restrictions, why the function must be bounded ?

Comment: Being bounded is not necessary for a function to be Riemann integrable.. What about $\frac 1{\sqrt x}$?

Comment: If $f$ is monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$, we have $f(a) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant f(b)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. For a monotonically decreasing function, the inequalities are reversed.

Comment: @Ant your function is Riemann integrable away from $0$.

Comment: Is it then not necessary to say that f(b) must be in R ?

Comment: @john well of course it's not defined in $0$, but the function is not bounded in $(0,1)$ and $$\int_0^1 \frac 1{\sqrt x} \ dx = 2$$

Comment: @Ant But that's an improper Riemann integral, the definition of Riemann integrability includes boundedness.

Comment: In order to be called Riemann integration, it has to be bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer and john: right, sorry, I overlooked that